# Unique values in Sencha Touch store

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am developing a mobile app in Sencha Touch and have the need to store details of previous searches locally without duplication.

The searching, storing and displaying works fine, however if I do the same search twice the entry gets duplicated in my store.

I expected that the "id" of the store would do this but something seems wrong.

Here is the code for the store.

```
    Ext.regModel('sSaved', {
        fields: [
            {name: 'IDs',        type: 'int'},
            {name: 'Outward',        type: 'string'},
            {name: 'Return',        type: 'string'},
            {name: 'Pickup',        type: 'string'},
            {name: 'Destination',        type: 'string'}
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            id:'IDs'
        }
    });             

    var savedJobs = new Ext.DataView({
        store: new Ext.data.Store({
            model: 'sSaved',
            storeId: 'allSaved'     
        }),
        tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for=".">',
                '<table class="item" style="margin:auto;">',
                    '<tr><td class="title">ID</td><td>{IDs}</td></tr>',
                    '<tr><td class="title">Outward</td><td>{Outward}</td></tr>',
                    '<tr><td class="title">Return</td><td>{Return}</td></tr>',
                    '<tr><td class="title">Pickup</td><td>{Pickup}</td></tr>',
                    '<tr><td class="title">Destination</td><td>{Destination}</td></tr>',
                '</table>',
            '</tpl>'
        ),
        itemSelector: "table.item",
        autoHeight:true,
        emptyText: 'No Saved Jobs',
        autoLoad: true
    });
```

And the code which sets the store.

```
    var fetched = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
    var details = fetched.apiResponse.details;
    savedJobs.store.load();
    savedJobs.store.add({
        "IDs":details.ID, 
        "Outward":details.Outward,
        "Return":details.Return,
        "Pickup":details.Pickup,
        "Destination":details.Destination
    });
    savedJobs.store.sync();
```

I could work around this by somehow searching the store and checking whether the value exists before adding, however I'm sure there is a simpler method.

If this search->check->add is the approach that's needed, what is the least resource intensive way?

Answer (score 1):

Checking for existing values won't hurt - I promise ;)  Also, you should do your add() AFTER the load() has finished. Since loading is asynchronous (without async: false in the config), you **MUST** either specify anything that depends on that data to happen 1) via the 'load' event of the store or 2) by specifying the callback method for the store's load config:

```
var fetched = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
var details = fetched.apiResponse.details;
savedJobs.store.load({
    callback: function() {
        if(!savedJobs.store.getById(details.ID) {
            savedJobs.store.add({
                "IDs":details.ID, 
                "Outward":details.Outward,
                "Return":details.Return,
                "Pickup":details.Pickup,
                "Destination":details.Destination
            });
        }
    }
});

savedJobs.store.sync();
```